# Node can't seemed to locate cors

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, express, cors

I installed cors then checked if it's inside the node_modules and confirmed that it's there but somehow, I always get this error.

> /usr/src/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859
> server  |     return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
> server  |            ^
> server  | TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
> server  | src/index.ts(3,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'cors' or its corresponding type declarations.

Anyone encountered this same issue?

Comment: I think you haven't installed types, install it by running `npm i -D @types/cors`

Comment: When running the container, do you have any volume mappings?

Answer (score 0):

try these, you have to hit and try since there can be many possibilities for this.

1.)

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

2.) npm install --save-dev @types/cors

3.) npm install typescript@latest --save-dev

4.) also check your tsconfig.json